# Prettify for generated string

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to apply prettify syntax highlighting to a generated string when the dropdown box is selected. It works fine if the text was placed before-hand, but if it is generated, the text is not highlighted. I've tried calling prettyPrint() function but it still does not work.

```
    $('#db').change(
        function(){
            query = "";
        query = "<pre class=\"prettyprint\" id=\"query\">Insert Into ";
            query = query + $('#db').val() + "</pre>";
            document.getElementById("pp").innerHTML = query;
            prettyPrint();
           $.ajax({
              url: "functions.php?&f=table",
              type: "GET",
              data: { db: $('#db').val() }
           }) 
           .done(function(result) {
                $('#table').html(result);
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert( "error" );
        });
        }
    );
```

Comment: On the console it says " Uncaught ReferenceError: prettyPrint is not defined ", though if it works without the generated string it means the script is referenced correctly right?

Comment: Do you have `prettyPrint` defined somewhere else? If it's not, that could wind up interrupting your execution

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/fB9bk/ its working fine, may be problem with prettyprint function

Comment: Prettyprint function is from Google's prettyprint library. There is no other function defined other than the <script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>

Comment: As per the documentation you dont need to call the function you just need to include it, have updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/fB9bk/ its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is detailed answer as per [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/wiki/GettingStarted)

If you load this script then you don't need to call the `prettyPrint()` function it will automatically prettify the content with class `prettyprint`

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

But if you load the css and js files separately then you need to call `prettyPrint()`

```
<link href="prettify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="prettify.js"></script>
```

**From documentation:** and then run the prettyPrint function once your page has finished loading. One way to do this is via the onload handler thus:

```
<body onload="prettyPrint()">
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/fB9bk/)** with script included rather than loading separate